# Would there be any particular reason to choose strawberries for this DNA extraction tutorial?

Tags: botany, dna-isolation

The NileRed video [What is DNA and what does it taste like? | Edible Chem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=araeHtN_3Lk) shows the extraction of a surprisingly large amount of DNA from some strawberries. At `02:22` the narrator says:

> What I think is really cool, is that it’s actually possible to isolate DNA from pretty much any living thing. For this video though, I’ve decided to get it from strawberries, because it’s one of the easiest sources.

I'm wondering if DNA is inherently easier to extract from strawberries than other fruits, vegetables, or other foods in general, or if for some reason there is more DNA (or DNA plus *other molecules bound to it*) it in strawberries than other foods to begin with.

[image: What is DNA and what does it taste like? | Edible Chem]

[image: What is DNA and what does it taste like? | Edible Chem]

Comment: As he is mentioning later in the video a "major reason" why he used strawberries, is that it's easy to crush them. In order to extract DNA from the tissue you need to damage the cells. We used tomatoes once, but with a blender. Works just as well..

Comment: @Frieke I was hoping for something more profound ;-( I am vaguely aware that some plants have absurdly huge genomes, and I was hoping that there was some amazing factoid about the strawberry genome being particularly huge.

Comment: @Frieke do you think that's worth posting as an answer? It does seem to answer my question, though *strawberries being easily crushable* is not the most profound sort of biology. I guess my other option is to delete the question.

Comment: A one-line answer without citations will attract the mods and downvotes. But I am not feeling like writing an essay about genome-sizes and crushability of fruits and vegetables ;)

Comment: @Frieke yep! okay thanks for the help, maybe I'll vote to close as off-topic and should be migrated to Cooking SE ;-)

Comment: It's on topic here and certainly not on topic at Cooking.SE.

Comment: @theforestecologist thanks for the encouragement; the smile emoticon was meant to indicate a bit of humor.

Comment: I figured as much, but I just thought I'd clarify just in case :p